# Back to the main content of a div box from a Jquery .load

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, ajax

I have a chatting system project php with a nav and has a child div called inbox where inbox has a children div.message and div.message__requests:

```
<div class="inbox">
 <div class="messages">
   <header>
     <nav>
        <a id="messages"><b>Messages</b></a><a id="messageRequests"><b>Message Requests</b></a>
    </nav>
    <hr>      
    <form action="includes/chatsearch-inc.php" method="POST">
       <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search a user or applicant\'s name">
       <button name="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
     </form>
    </header>
    <section>';
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT usersId ='".$_SESSION['userid']."';";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           echo '<div class="user__container">
                     <input type="hidden" data-userid="'.$row['usersId'].'">
                     <img src="profilepic/'.$row['usersProfilePic'].'">
                     <div class="user">
                          <p><b>'.$row['usersName'].'</b></p>
                          <p class="message">You: dssasdas</p>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <hr>';
           }
        echo '</section>
          </div>
          <div class="message__requests">
            <nav>
              <a id="messages"><b>Messages</b></a><a id="messageRequests"><b>Message Requests</b></a>
            </nav>    
            <section>
               <div class="user__container">
                   <img src="profilepic/'.$profilepic.'">
                    <div class="user">
                       <p><b>'.$_SESSION['username'].'</b></p>
                       <p class="message">asdasdsd</p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <hr>
                 <div class="user__container">
                     <img src="profilepic/'.$profilepic.'">
                     <div class="user">
                          <p><b>'.$_SESSION['username'].'</b></p>
                          <p class="message">asdasdsd</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
              </section>
            </div>
           </div>
```

Where div.messages shows the users inbox like the home screen of facebook messenger app.

If I click the said nav, the inbox will pop in the middle of the screen and the div.message is the default content.

Now when I click a div.user__container inside my div.messages, I can load the user chat box, like when you click a user in facebook messenger inside the div.messages, replacing all the content of div.messages with what I have in my other php file (simulating a real time chat box):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages AS m LEFT JOIN users AS u ON m.outgoingUsersId = u.usersId WHERE (incomingUsersId = '$incoming' AND outgoingUsersId = '$outgoing') OR (incomingUsersId = '$outgoing' AND outgoingUsersId = '$incoming') ORDER BY msgId DESC;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if ($row['outgoingUsersId'] == $outgoing) {
                $output .= '<div class="chat outgoing">
                              <div class="message">
                                <p>'.$row['msgContent'].'</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>';
            }
            else {
                $output .= '<div class="chat incoming">
                              <img src="profilepic/'.$row['usersProfilePic'].'">
                              <div class="message">
                                <p>'.$row['msgContent'].'</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>';
            }
        }
        echo $output;
    }
```

And I can achieve this all by my jquery call:

```
$('section .user__container').click(function() {
        var userid = $(this).children('input').data('userid');
        $('.inbox .messages').load('includes/ajax-load/chatpage-aload.php', 
        {
            usersid : userid
        }, function() {

            $('.user__inbox header i').click(function() {
                // I want to load back to div.messages content
            });

            var sender = $('#chatForm #chatSender').val();
            var receiver = $('#chatForm #chatReceiver').val();

            setInterval(() => {
                    $.post('includes/ajax-func/getchat-afunc.php', {
                        outgoingUsersId : sender,
                        incomingUsersId : receiver
                    }, function (response) {
                        $('.user__inbox section').html(response);
                    });
                }, 500
            );

            $('#chatForm').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                
                var message = $('#chatForm input[type="text"]').val();
                $.post('includes/ajax-func/insertchat-afunc.php', {
                    outgoingUsersId : sender,
                    incomingUsersId : receiver,
                    message : message
                }, function (data) {
                    $('#chatForm input[type="text"]').val("");
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

My question is, how can I go back to the main content of div.messages (like how users in messenger app can go bck to the home screen when the click the back button beside the users info in their header) without reloading the whole webpage, when I click the:

```
$('.user__inbox header i').click(function() {
    // I want to load back to div.messages content
});
```

Or any recommendations to my code? Thanks

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any help please thanks!